Could not find androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6
I want to use Fetch library to download APK files, when adding the dependency to build.gradle file and sync gradle, I get an error:

Could not find androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6. Required by:
project :app Search in build.gradle files

I get this error usually when using libraries that are old, what causes the error, and are there other libraries for downloading files?

That library has not been updated in nearly four years and was only on JCenter. JCenter is deprecated as an artifact repository.

What's the workaround? So this library can't be used anymore?

@JafferAlfahdawi did you get any solution for this ?

@SanalKv not yet

maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
implementation "com.github.tonyofrancis.Fetch:fetch2:3.3.0"
this worked.
